# Why isn't Entrez NCBI API error handling working?

Tags: api, exception, try-catch, biopython, ncbi

```
from Bio import Entrez, __version__

print('Biopython version : ', __version__)

id_list = ["NC_045512.2", "ON248099.1", "ON248101.1", "ON248104.1", "ON248107.1", "ON248108.1", "ON248109.1", "ON248110.1", "ON248114.1", "ON247234.1", "ON247236.1", "ON247240.1", "ON247242.1", "ON247243.1", "ON247244.1", "ON247245.1", "ON247246.1", "ON247247.1", "ON247248.1"]
   
try:
    print ("Downloading "+str(id_list[ax]))
    net_handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=id_list[ax], rettype="fasta", retmode="text")
    net_handle_gb = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=id_list[ax], rettype="gbwithparts", retmode="text")
except (IOError):
    print ("Waiting")
    sleep (30)
    tell.app( 'Terminal', 'do script "' + command+ ' && ' + "python3 'All Covid SSR.py'" +'"')
```

I'm using this `try` block to download files from NCBI API. Up to this point, the `try` block was working and the exception was handled as given here. Now it isn't. The code gets stuck in the `try` section. Returns no errors or exceptions, so it doesn't trigger the exception handler.

I've set `max_tries = 1`, `sleep_between_tries = 1` and got the personal API_Key too.

For context, I'm using the exceptions block to restart the downloading code on Mac Terminal.

I need the `try` and `except` section to automatically restart the script when `Entrez.efetch` returns an error. There isn't any error. The code just gets stuck after

```
                    print ("Downloading "+str(id_list[ax]))
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

P.S. I thought of changing the default timeout for `requests.get` because that's the module Entrez uses to access the NCBI API. Haven't found a way to do that. (There is no timeout variable that you can set in the `efetch` module.)

An explanation would be great!

Comment: cannnot run  your code please provide complete full reproducible example --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  ,  
NameError: name 'id_list' is not defined

Comment: id_list is a list accession numbers I am using to run a loop on and get each file by the ID number from the API. For testing you can use this id_list = [NC_045512.2, ON248099.1,ON248101.1,ON248104.1,ON248107.1,ON248108.1,ON248109.1,ON248110.1,ON248114.1,ON247234.1,ON247236.1,ON247240.1,ON247242.1,ON247243.1,ON247244.1,ON247245.1,ON247246.1,ON247247.1,ON247248.1]

Comment: list in python have string element inbetween quotes/double quotes

Comment: and what is the meaning of id_list[ax] ?? Is it like for ax in range(len(id_list)):
    
    print(id_list[ax])

Comment: yes, that's right. Sorry about the poorly written question. New to Stack. Thanks for editing the original question on my behalf. 

I load the id_list by opening a csv file with pandas and then add a column using tolist() method. I wasn't sure if the objects were added as strings or not in that method. So I manually created the list for this example.